# Will a lid with a hole in it work with a crock pot?

Tags: equipment, crockpot

I have an older crock pot, and the lid needs to be replaced. It's an odd size, and the only appropriate lid I could find has a tiny hole in it for venting. Will the crock pot still work normally if it's vented?

Comment: Tiny steam holes are actually fairly normal on slow cooker lids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a rice cooker lid as a replacement on an old crock pot. It has a small venting hole as you described.

I have been using this lid for years now and have yet to have a dish dry out. The hole is just too small to let much water out.

Comment: Mine has a hole in the lid for a probe thermometer to be inserted ... like you said, it's so small (maybe 1/8" / 3mm) that things don't dry out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work with some tinkering. Many older crock pot lids had a flap which could be opened or closed to allow steam to vent if a recipe started out especially wet. If you don't want to dry out your food, I'd suggest wrapping the lid with aluminum foil first to keep the hole mostly covered, or plan to add additional liquid in the beginning to make up for moisture lost due to evaporation.

Comment: Nice tip with the aluminum foil!